# Symfony 3 or 4 Custom Translation Loader

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am very confused by symfony translation module. 
How can one configure a custom translation loader in the config files?

I have my custom loader an it works, based on this example:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/custom_formats.html

This works, if I put it in a controller

```
        $translator = new Translator( 'de' );
        $translator->addLoader( 'my_format', new MyCsvLoader() );
        $translator->addResource( 'my_format', $root . '/translations/translations.csv', 'de' );

        var_dump( $translator->trans( 'LB_ABOUT' ) );
```

But I cannot figure it out how can I register this as my "default" translation loader; as this should be used by default.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-translation-loader

**translation.yaml**

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'en'
    translator:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations/'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

**services.yaml:**

```
App\Translate\MyCsvLoader:
    tags:
        - { name: translation.loader, alias: csv }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a priority? E.g. `{ name: translation.loader, alias: csv, priority: 100 }` ?

Comment: Added that, still the same, the MyCsvLoader doesn't even get called. Imo, I am missing smth in the configuration

Comment: I fiddled around with this a bit and found that the loader only get's *asked* to load a resource when a fitting translation file is present. Meaning `{domain}.{locale}.{extension}` in any `translator.paths` with `{extension}` being the same as the alias on the `translation.loader` tag. You might want to check if `$root` in your working code equals `'%kernel.project_dir%/translations/'` from the configuration. That said, I wonder why you need an extra loader, as a csv-loader is already available (which could also be the root cause, as it might overwrite your loader definition)?

Comment: I'm looking for this too, I want to modify the xlf loader Symfony uses to use "id" instead of resname, but am struggling to find a clean way of doing it, one idea was a customer loader, but I want it to be default

Comment: did you try changing `default_locale: 'en'` to `default_locale: 'de'` ?

Comment: I can't talk about SF3 for now but in SF4 your configuration is ok. The `Translator` component use by default `DelegatinLoader` which define the best loader to use for a file. This is why the `alias` parameter is important. This alias define the file extension of your custom translation loader. There is already on loader for CSV: [https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader/CsvFileLoader.php]. But take really care of the SF version. What i'm telling you here is about 4.x

Answer (score 1):

i did some test and your configuration is ok. But you have to respect some rules to make it right. Symfony is trying to load catalog from a locale. So you have to put this locale in your filename: `translations.de.csv`

Like i said in my comment the loader is only to load data then the magic happens and symfony take care to put messages in the catalog. The right loader is resolved and use by a `DelegatingLoader` class, that's why you have to configure an alias in the tag's service.

here a demo:

#### Services.yaml

```
App\Translate\MyCsvLoader:
        tags:
            - { name: translation.loader, alias: csv }
```

#### Translation config

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'en'
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

#### Loader Service

```php
<?php

namespace App\Translate;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\Exception\NotFoundResourceException;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\FileLoader;

class MyCsvLoader extends FileLoader
{
    private $delimiter = ';';
    private $enclosure = '"';
    private $escape = '\\';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function loadResource($resource)
    {
        $messages = [];

        try {
            $file = new \SplFileObject($resource, 'rb');
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            throw new NotFoundResourceException(sprintf('Error opening file "%s".', $resource), 0, $e);
        }

        $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV | \SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);
        $file->setCsvControl($this->delimiter, $this->enclosure, $this->escape);

        foreach ($file as $data) {
            if ('#' !== substr($data[0], 0, 1) && isset($data[1]) && 2 === \count($data)) {
                $messages[$data[0]] = $data[1];
            }
        }

        return $messages;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the delimiter, enclosure, and escape character for CSV.
     *
     * @param string $delimiter Delimiter character
     * @param string $enclosure Enclosure character
     * @param string $escape    Escape character
     */
    public function setCsvControl($delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\')
    {
        $this->delimiter = $delimiter;
        $this->enclosure = $enclosure;
        $this->escape    = $escape;
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```php
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/test", name="test", requirements={"_locale": "en|fr"})
 */
public function index()
{
    return $this->render('index.html.twig');
}
```

#### Twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <p>{{ 'symfony.great'|trans }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

#### messages.en.csv

```
symfony.great;Symfony is great
```

#### messages.fr.csv

```
symfony.great;Symfony est génial
```